# How to migrate localStorage to AsyncStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have already a localStorage code for my web project.

My localStorage file for save and load localStorage.

```
// localStorage.js
export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    localStorage.clear();
    const version = localStorage.getItem("version");
    // you can update the version to init the persist state
    if (version !== "0.1") {
      localStorage.clear();
      localStorage.setItem("version", "0.1");
    }
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem("state");
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};
export const saveState = state => {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem("state", serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    // Ignore write errors.
  }
};
```

And my store file to init the redux store.

```
// store.js
import persistReducer from "./reducers/persistReducer";
...

import { loadState, saveState } from "./localStorage";

const persistedState = loadState();

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
    persist: persistReducer,
    ...
  }),
  persistedState,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

store.subscribe(
  throttle(() => {
    saveState({
      persist: store.getState().persist
    });
  }, 1000)
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    ...
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

Now I want to migrate this code to AsyncStorage, how could simply change this code to adjust for my native app project?

Comment: What did you try and what was the problem?

Comment: How to make the AsyncStorage a reducer like function? To store the key/value under nameSpace.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. They are apples and oranges. AsyncStorage doesn't work as a reducer (neither is localStorage). In the code you posted the difference is that loadState returns a promise, this makes app initialization asynchronous.

Comment: I think there is a way to combine all AsyncStorage to one place, rather than to per load/save item.

Comment: I see what you mean. This should be custom middleware that does `saveState` automatically, not a reducer. But this won't help with `loadState`. Otherwise you would ended up with empty initial state.